# C# byte[] back to List<int>

Tags: c#

I have a List that I'm converting to a byte[] like so:

```
List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

integerList.Add(1);
integerList.Add(2);
integerList.Add(3);

byte[] bytes = integerList.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray();
```

How do I convert this back to a List?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the many ways to do it (a LINQ one):

```
var originalList = Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length / 4)
                             .Select(i => BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, i * 4))
                             .ToList();
```

**Minor update:**

You can also write a handy generic version of this (just in case you'll need to work with other types):

```
static List<T> ToListOf<T>(byte[] array, Func<byte[], int, T> bitConverter)
{
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    return Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length / size)
                     .Select(i => bitConverter(array, i * size))
                     .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
var originalList = ToListOf<int>(bytes, BitConverter.ToInt32);
```

Comment: Great answer. The problem is that the int size Nate is trying to parse is not consistently 4 bytes.

Comment: Updated answer: added generic version which will work with any types

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] is an IEnumerable; LINQ's ToList() extension method should do it.
```

EDIT: If you want a list of int's:

```
bytes.Select((b) => (int)b).toList();
```

Comment: Yes; is that not what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that just produces a list of bytes, just tested it.

Comment: @Mellvar: I didn't ask the question, but I don't believe that is what they are asking either. They converted a List of ints to a byte array so I would imagine they would want a List of the same ints out of any proposed solution.

Comment: @Mellvar Nope :).  I'm trying to put this list in an azure queue and it requires me to put it in as a bytearray (or a string but I don't want to do that).  

your most recent code returns a list of 12 integers where every 4th integer is the correct one in the series (1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0)

Comment: @Nate: That's good to know - seems like a horribly inefficient thing to do otherwise :) If that's what you're seeing, then your byte array must be 12 elements-long too

Comment: @Nate: That is because an Int32 is 4 bytes and you are using values smaller than 16.

Comment: @M.Babcock My integers will be of variable size. This solution doesn't work if you have larger ints too. ie(3645465)

Comment: @Nate: The byte array you want to parse has to be predictable. If it isn't then this wont be possible.

Comment: @Nate: The answer you selected will only work if the values are in the range of an Int32 (4 bytes).

Comment: @M.Babcock Thanks, good to know.  This is for IDs in a database in my startup; so hopefully I'll hit 2 billion pretty soon and have to ask the same question for int64 ;).

Comment: @Nate: I'm no expert on Azure, but there _has_ to be a better way to do this. The solutions being discussed are far from optimal or practical.

Comment: @Mellvar It's for async processing after it's in the queue, so time isn't that big of a deal.  I could also just pass a string, so I could have encoded this in XML or JSON or even CSV.  I thought this solution would be better than those...but like I said it doesn't matter too much.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179346.aspx